# How to see the User that created a table in SSMS?

Tags: sql-server, ssms

Is it possible to see which user created a particular table in SSMS 18.7 (SQL Server 2016)?

I have a lot of tables but I do not know who created them.

Every user that access the SQL Server have an account name, so it should be possible, should it not?

Any ideas?

Comment: pretty sure that this detail isn't tracked anywhere in SQL Server. it _might_ be possible to interrogate the transaction log to get some of it, or to correlate the creation time of the table in the metadata with connections in the general SQL server log, but it's not exposed in DMVs

Comment: It may still be in [the default trace](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/48052/1186).

Comment: The schema changes history report uses the default trace as the source so you many still have the info if it was created recently. Right-click the server in SSMS Object Explorer and select Reports-->Standard Reports--Schema Changes History.

Comment: @DanGuzman you have right. But it seems that the information is not complete.

Comment: That's right... default trace is not a permanent audit history of all time, and the retention there will depend not on time but on what other activity you throw at it.